# Why does using $(gcloud auth print-identity-token) throw 401 but plain id-token works?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud, google-client

If I try to provide authentication credentials in my request as a generated `ID token` stored in an Authorization header:

```bash
curl -m 550 -X POST https://origin-project.cloudfunctions.net/myfunction \
-H "Authorization: bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{}'
```

I get `401 Unauthorized`:

```html
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>401 Unauthorized</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Unauthorized</h1>
<h2>Your client does not have permission to the requested URL <code>/myfunction</code>.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
```

But if I manually insert the ID token like below, it works:

```bash
curl -m 550 -X POST https://origin-project.cloudfunctions.net/myfunction \
-H "Authorization: bearer eyM5NjBJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOztszEgUX4oH.YI80RjsZdxSFIcFshmA" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{}'
```

Response:

```
Request payload is empty: None
```

Does anyone know why this is so?

**Note**: I'm executing commands locally via `Google Cloud CLI`.

Comment: The plain text token is also generated with the `gcloud auth print-identity-token` command? in the same environment?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yes, that is correct. However the plain token used in the question is just a dummy string.